# I don't understand boolean truths in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I wrote this code (`x` was run through a `str()` before this scope):

```
if x == "A" or "O":
    return x
```

This returns `B` when `x = B`. Can someone help me understand why `x = B` validates here?

When I changed my code to read

```
if x == "A":
    return x
elif x == "O":
    return x
```

It did not match `x = B`, so I am assuming there is something with the boolean logic here that I am not understanding.

Comment: `x == "A" or "O"` == `(x == "A") or "O"`

Comment: Thank you Ashwini! Makes complete sense now.

Comment: In python boolean `if "<any character here>"` will evaluate to true
since you have specified 

`if x == "A" or "O":`

though first condition is false it will check next condition and will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if x == "A" or "O":` should be `if x == "A" or x == "O":`.

`if x == "A" or "O":` will always be evaluated to `true`.

---

`if x == "A" or "O":` is interpreted as:

`if (x == "A") or ("O")`, `"O"` is `true`, so even if `x` is not `"A"`, since you have `or`, this will always be `true`.

Alternatively you can write:

```
if x in ["A", "O"]:
```